# Pegar o status de permissão quando o usuário tiver dado permissão ao acesso de localização runtime no Android

Tags: java, android, gps

Estou pegando os dados de localização utilizando o `LocationManager` no Android e gostaria de saber como posso pegar a ação **apenas** se o usuário **permitir** que o app acesse seus dados de localização.

Por exemplo, utilizando o código abaixo, consigo pegar de acordo com a permissão positiva do usuário, preciso antes que ele aceite a permissão para depois trabalhar em cima

Porém, eu preciso pegar o dado preciso caso o usuário já tenha permitido ou não, para aí sim trabalhar em cima desse dado independente dele aceitar ou não. É possível?

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       //O que precisa fazer se a permissão for aceita.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Existem bibliotecas que podem te auxiliar nessa tarefa. Isso reduz a quantidade de linhas de código e facilita sua vida e de quem for utilizar seu código posteriormente, se for o caso.

As minhas duas preferidas são: [PermissionManager](https://github.com/karanchuri/PermissionManager) e a [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)

Comment: Obrigado, brother. Acho que será melhor eu implementar uma biblioteca mesmo até mesmo pra tratar as exceções das permissões. Mas será que não existe nenhuma forma de pegar o stastus apenas o status se já foi permitido ou não as permissões runtime? Valeuu!